# Is it wrong to call yourself Dr First_Name Last_Name when you have a Professional Doctorate such as DTech or DBA and not a PhD or MBBS?

Tags: phd, titles, australia

Is it wrong to call yourself Dr First_Name Last_Name when you have a Professional Doctorate such as [DTech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Technology) or [DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Business_Administration) and not a PhD or [MBBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Medicine,_Bachelor_of_Surgery)?

Comment: Your country?  Where I live, you can call officially yourself Dr only if the title you obtained is exactly Dr.

Comment: And also, called by whom? Your friends? Your parents? Official documents? Pleaseclarify the question.

Comment: @user111388 Thank you for your answer, however, "Where I live, you can call officially yourself Dr only if the title you obtained is exactly Dr." <---this is a nonsense answer as there are many physicians for example who can officially call themselves Dr. but didn't receive a Dr. as they received a MBBS. That is to say, there is no Dr. degree, but there is PhD, DPhil, DEng, MBBS, etc. My question is can a DTech recipient officially call themselves a Dr. Given that DTech is like a DBA (Dr of Business Administration), it is a professional degree that isn't externally examined with a viva voce

Comment: Why do you call my answer nonsense? Indeed, in my country, there is a Dr. title and only if you recieved this title, you can call yourself Dr. in official documents.  It might be different in your country but then you might want to state it.

Comment: I am from Australia. I have attached a sample Doctoral Testamur with URL https://live.staticflickr.com/7233/7158848837_b12e2f8e76_b.jpg
The recipient is Michael Bernard Hale, not Dr. Michael Bernard Hale.
That said, it is well know that having a PhD was the original way one would be called Doctor (i.e. teacher).
My question is whether having a DTech allows one to formally/officially to be designated as a Dr.
P.S. I don't have a DTech but a PhD.

Comment: Please note that this is NOT just an Australian question, but in general from different countries. For example, one can obtain a DTech from the UK.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? If there is any country in the world where it is against the law to call yourself Dr. without a Dr. title?

Comment: My contention is that if someone obtains a DTech or a DBA, regardless of where they obtain it in the world, then they should not use the Dr. designation. There are already many others, such as BAppSci (Chiropractor), BAppSci (Osteopathy) that call themselves Dr. I think as there are so many degrees that allow one to be called Dr, that "Dr" will become meaningless.

Comment: Removal of my clarification edit was not helpful. If you want an authoritative answer you should make your question as clear as possible. This is not a chat board.

Comment: The rules for title use differ from country to country. So, without specifying the country as context in the question, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @user111388: "Where I live, you can call officially yourself Dr only if the title you obtained is exactly Dr." Where is that?

Comment: I was using P.S. as in the end of a letter (i.e. "post scriptum"), not as a degree.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Suggest you read the title before commenting. Did you not know that MDs obtain a MBBS or equivalent? What did you think I meant by MBBS?

Comment: @HanzSchmidt I just learned something new.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is highly dependant on legislation (of the country where you are when you are calling yourself). In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) (AFAIK, one of the more picky legislations wrt what you can call yourself):

Let's assume you move to Germany with a proper DTech from South Africa, Australia, UK or Sweden. Proper meaning: scientific thesis, degree from a university (or similar recognied highest level institution), honorary degrees have separate rules, bought degrees cannot be used in Germany.

- For South Africa, the most general rules apply: you are `Firstname Lastname, DTech (University of ...)`* you can also *add* a translation: `(Doktor der Technologie)`.
  If the country doesn't use the latin alphabet, you can transliterate. And long form or usual abbreviation are both fine.

  * Whether you put the degree before or after the name doesn't matter.
- For Australia, there is a treaty on equivalency of degrees and [in consequence (legal text in German)](https://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/ZAB/Gradfuehrung_Beschluesse_der_KMK/20150626_KMK-Beschluss_Beguenstigende_Regelungen.pdf) you are `Dr. Firstname Lastname`. *Not* Dr.-Ing., though.
- Since Sweden is member of EU (same for EWR), with a Swedish DTech, you have the choice. You can either be `Firstname Lastname, DTech` or `Dr. Firstname Lastname`. Again, not Dr.-Ing. even though that is the German degree corresponding to the Swedish DTech.

  This does not apply to so-called Berufsdoktorate where the doctor is awarded not for a research thesis but automatically when finishing a Master level education.
- UK used to be in the EU until recently and the offical texts have not yet caught up with Brexit. I saw a note somewhere that UK degrees are still treated like EU.

---

German doctorate degrees are mostly of the form `Dr. ... ...`, e.g. I'm `Dr. rer. nat.` (doctor in natural things [sciences], in my case chemistry).

- When addressing a person, usually at most the "doctor" is pronounced, the type/field only if that is considered important for the specific occasion.
- I could ask to have the doctor put into my ID card where it would appear as `DR` (the line is all uppercase) only, without specifying what kind of doctor I am.
- I could also put the doctor to my doorbell, either as `Dr. rer. nat. C. Beleites` (sounds very arrogant, unless it is part of the professional doorbell `Chemometric Consulting Dr. rer. nat. C. Beleites` where I'd think it only a bit stuffy -  as it is, the office door bell actually reads `Chemometric Consulting C. Beleites`) or as `Dr. C. Beleites` (slightly arrogant). Only my business card contains in small print the information that I'm Dr. rer. nat. and Dipl.-Chem. (since one cannot know from Dr. rer. nat. that I'm chemist).

---

> BAppSci (Chiropractor), BAppSci (Osteopathy) that call themselves Dr.

This is not allowed in Germany. Even a physician can call themselves Dr. only if they actually obtained a doctor degree. Otherwise, they are
`Firstname Lastname, Arzt` (physician, meaning they passed their state exams and got approbated) or `Firstname Lastname, Facharzt für ...` (meaning they also passed the specialization exam for field ...).

If they also did their doctorate, they are `Dr. med. Firstname Lastname, Facharzt für ...`.

---

> whether having a DTech allows one to formally/officially to be designated as a Dr. P.S.

Not in Germany.

In some faculties, the candidate can ask to get e.g. a `Ph. D.` rather than the usual `Dr. rer. nat.`. But once that degree is awarded, one has to stick with it.